# Quicksort sampling

Tags: sorting, combinatorics, quicksort

This question is in the context of quicksort. Consider that a subarray of distinct elements of size $k$ is sampled from the input array of size $n$, and then we choose a pivot from the sampled subarray. We want to compute and bound the probability that the element of rank $s$ in the original array lies in the middle third of the sampled array.

This is my attempt. We know that the probability that the elemenet of rank $s$ in the original array is the element of rank $q$ in the subarray is
$$ \frac{{s-1\choose q-1} {n-s\choose k-q}}{n \choose k},$$ thus the probability that the element of rank $s$ in the original array lies in the middle third of the sampled array would be
$$ \sum^{2k/3}_{j=k/3} \frac{{s-1\choose j-1} {n-s\choose k-j}}{n \choose k}.$$ I found a bound using Vandermonde's identity that leads to $\frac{n-1\choose k-1}{n\choose k} = k/n$, but it is not tight enough for my needs. Any ideas how to find a tighter bound?